# The literary output of Rabbi Jack Simcha Cohen

Tags: jewish-books

I just read and enjoyed a [long piece](https://www.jewishideas.org/articles/modern-orthodoxy-definitions-and-insights) by [Rabbi Jack Simcha Cohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Simcha_Cohen). The little biog attached said he was a "prolific author", but doesn't give any indication of whether all of his output has been in a similar vein (e.g. examining Modern Orthodoxy's approach to halacha).

Looking through the catalogues of online retailers, his output seems to consist mostly of collections of answers to specific questions. For example, here is a quote from the blurb to *How Does Jewish Law Work?*:

> ....provides both the answers to questions of Jewish law and a look at the process by which the answers are derived. According to Rabbi Cohen, *"Halachah, the distinctly unique Jewish legal system, crystallizes the guidelines of Judaism. It makes us into Jews and marks us as Jewish. As such, an understanding of the halachic process provides insight into the inner soul of Jewish life itself."*
>
> In this book, Rabbi Cohen explores issues surrounding charity, Jewish communal concerns, repentance and rebuke, marriage and family life, rituals, Sabbath and holiday observances, and prayers.
>
> A companion volume to his previous best-seller, Timely Jewish Questions, Timeless Rabbinic Answers, How Does Jewish Law Work? clearly presents each question and carefully details the process of finding its answer. Through explication of verses from the Torah, talmudic passages, and other sources, the reader receives the answer to the question and is also given the background information to see how a rabbi arrives at the halachic decision.

Volumes identified:

*Timely Jewish Questions, Timeless Rabbinic Answers*
*How Does Jewish Law Work*
*How Does Jewish Law Work II*
*Shabbat, The Right Way*
*Jewish Prayer, The Right Way*
*Intermarriage And Conversion*
*The 613th Commandment*
*The Jewish Heart*
*Jewish Poverty Issues*

**Do any of these volumes have an especial reputation?**

Comment: https://www.jewishideas.org/rabbi-jack-simcha-cohen

Comment: Please clarify with an [edit] to the question what you would consider a good book. There is no "general reader": some like science fiction, some like political op-eds, some like programming-language manuals, some like recipe books; some like English-language pieces, some like Hebrew-; some like succinct writing, some like verbose; some like broad, shallow coverage of a subject, some like deep coverage of a narrower subject; some like Braille; some like... well, you get the point.

Comment: @msh210 The piece linked to is (a) by a English-speaking Rabbi (b) on the subject of halacha (c) compares the approaches of Modern Orthodoxy and Hassidim. This website is about Judaism. I am writing in English. What makes you think that any of the following are relevant to a general enquiry based on this one piece of evidence: science fiction; political op-eds; programming-language; recipe books; books in Hebrew; books published in Braille?

Comment: @msh210 As for broad scope vs deep, narrow attention - it depends. If the author writes broad wide-ranging books well, but intensely-focussed ones badly, I had imagined that a considerate reply would recommend the former. If on the other hand...well, you get my point.

Comment: @chrysanthemum You should always [edit] to respond instead of leaving information in the comments. Comments are subject to removal at any time, and posts can't be opened or closed based on content in the comments. Please remember this for the future. Please remember as well that [tag:product-recommendation] requests need specific guidelines to match a product to in order to avoid being too subjective. Seeking a "good X" is not a good question for here. (Note you currently don't even seek "good books" but just want to know which books would be recommended to whom. Always better to be explicit.)

Comment: @DoubleAA since I'm faced within unknown unknowns, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to introduce specificity. Have completely reworded question.

Comment: It was actually surprising difficult to find this (due to how the name is abbreviated, I think), but it seems like Amazon has an authors page for Rabbi J. Simcha Cohen: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?ie=UTF8&text=J.+Simcha+Cohen&search-alias=books&field-author=J.+Simcha+Cohen&sort=relevancerank This might help you find some of his titles.

Comment: I think the edited question is clear and within our scope.

Comment: @Salmononius2 thanks; I'd started trying to make my way through the murk of Amazon already- I hadn't previously found individual author's pages :) I haven't yet found a review of any of his books elsewhere online, so I've no idea which ones might be recommended above others. However, it seems that all of them follow a similar pattern of setting a series of halachic questions and then answering them in a clear discursive manner. I would put what little is available online in an Answer but question is on hold. The Google Books page on "How Does Jewish Law Work" gives a fairly useful description

Comment: @MonicaCellio I have put what little information I've found online into the question, and narrowed the scope of the question yet further

Comment: Title of all volumes I've found reference to online added to question

Comment: @Salmononius2 I've just found that the search function of the Jewish Book Review website is bearing fruit, too

Comment: @msh210 am unsure why this question is still on hold

Comment: Because, until you just pinged me, I was unaware of the edits and because the reopen-closed-questions reviewers didn't reopen it (if indeed it got to that review queue.  I haven't checked). And because the other moderators involved in this comment thread didn't deem it reopenable or didn't have a chance. Looks good now IMO. I'll reopen.

Comment: If one is interested in ascertaining anything specific vis-a-vis Rabbi J. Simcha Cohen (zt'l)--my father--then please feel free to contact me. (Rabbi Judah Z. Cohen, Esq.) (Juddzc@gmail.com)

Comment: Here is a picture of him, taken from [here](http://mizrachi.com.au/content/history-then-and-now), apparently during the period of time when he lived in Melbourne, Australia. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sbug.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sbug.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Since some information is better than no information....

Online, collected on the Jewish Book Review blog, I found [several reviews](https://jewishbookreview.wordpress.com/?s=Rabbi%20Simcha%20Cohen) of *Shabbat, The Right Way*, and *Jewish Prayer, The Right Way*. In general they were [appreciative](https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/12/2011/shabbat-the-right-way-resolving-halachic-dilemmas/), though one or two noted places where Rabbi Simcha Cohen's conclusions were [outside the flow](https://jewishbookreview.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/the-jewish-press-reviews-shabbat-the-right-way/#more-1757) of halachic opinion. I ordered [*Jewish Prayer*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9655240681), and found a couple of comments in the introduction which, edited down, might be useful:

> In 1983 I presented the Chief Rabbi of Israel with a copy of my [*The 613th Commandment: An Analysis of the Mitzvah to Write a Sefer Torah*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881250279). [He said] "It is wise that your first book is a scholarly treatise. Now that you have established your experise in both Talmud and Halacha with this volume, you may concentrate upon other subject matter". I never did solely concentrate on other subject matter. Halacha was always my prime area of concern .... My mission was and is to dispel the erroneous notion that Halacha is dry and not as meaningful a pursuit as other aspects of Torah learning.

After his death in the summer of 2014, The Jewish Press published [this memorial profile](http://www.jewishpress.com/indepth/interviews-and-profiles/a-silken-man-made-of-the-finest-fibers-remembering-rabbi-jack-simcha-cohen/2014/08/06/0/)